# Java Rotate Image Towards Point from any X/Y position on screen

Tags: java, object, sprite, move

I have a ship object that I want to be able to rotate towards any certain point I click on the screen (See pic of ship and sqaures as points). I can get the ship to face the general direction, but it has this strange behavior of as it rotates the ship itself; the image moves around an circular axis, instead of rotating from the center point of the image itself.

Can someone please, give me the formula to get the angle from the center xy point of image to the destination sqaure(mouse click)?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the difference on the x axis and the difference on the y axis. Since you seem to say that your ship is centered, you only have to get the (x,y) coordinates of the click. To find the angle, you must know that sin(your angle) = y/sqrt(y^2 + x^2), therefore, your angle = sin^-1(y/sqrt(y^2 + x^2)). It is basic maths, but it's always good to refresh basic knowledge, as it can cause quite the headache when debugging if you made a small mistake there, so I suggest you check out this page:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html

Answer (score 0):

> but it has this strange behavior of as it rotates the ship itself; the image moves around an circular axis, instead of rotating from the center point of the image itself.

You need to rotate the image about its center point, which means you need to translate the Graphics object to the center of your image before you paint the image.

This example rotates about a fixed point:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Rotation2 extends JPanel
{
    BufferedImage image;
    int degrees;
    int point = 250;

    public Rotation2(BufferedImage image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        setDegrees( 0 );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(600, 600) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );
        g2.translate(point, point);
        g2.rotate(radians);
        g2.translate(-image.getWidth(this) / 2, -image.getHeight(this) / 2);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2.dispose();

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(point - 5, point - 5, 10, 10);
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String path = "mong.jpg";
//                  String path = "dukewavered.gif";
                    ClassLoader cl = Rotation2.class.getClassLoader();
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(cl.getResourceAsStream(path));
                    final Rotation2 r = new Rotation2(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                    f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.