# Why are there these weird visual artifacts when scrolling my BufferedImage? And how do I prevent them from happening?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, graphics2d, visual-glitch

I am creating an application that involves drawing a `BufferedImage` to a `JComponent` using `Graphics2D` in a `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.

I added the ability to zoom in and out of the image. The `JComponent` I am drawing to is contained within a `JScrollPane`. If the image becomes zoomed in enough, scrollbars appear.

Whenever I scroll the `JScrollPane`, I get weird visual artifacts.

Here is the zoomed out version of my image.

[image: Zoomed out version of the image]

Here is the zoomed in version of my image, with no visual artifacts.

[image: Zoomed in version of the image]

And here is what it looks like when I scroll down a bit, and then to the right.

[image: Zoomed in version of the image with weird visual artifacts]

Upon discovering this, I added a button that just triggers a `repaint()` and `revalidate()` call on the relevant `JComponent`. Doing that fixed it.

BEFORE PRESSING THE REPAINT BUTTON ON THE TOP RIGHT

[image: Before pressing REPAINT]

AFTER PRESSING THE REPAINT BUTTON ON THE TOP RIGHT

[image: After pressing REPAINT]

Here is the relevant portion of the code that handles painting the `BufferedImage` to the `JComponent`.

```java
@Override
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics dontUse)
{

   super.paintComponent(dontUse);

   if (!(dontUse instanceof Graphics2D g))
   {
   
      throw new RuntimeException("Unknown graphics type = " + dontUse);
   
   }

   DRAW_DRAWN_PIXELS:
   {
   
      final Rectangle rectangle  = gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();
   
      //We are only drawing a subsection because we may be working with GIGANTIC images.
      //If we attempt to draw the whole image, performance will drop like a rock.
      CALCULATE_SUBSECTION_TO_DRAW:
      {
      
         final int x = rectangle.x;
         final int y = rectangle.y;
         final int width = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
         final int height = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);
      
         g.setBackground(gui.transparencyColor);
         g.clearRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, width, height);
      
      }
   
      DRAW_SUBSECTION_OF_IMAGE:
      {
      
         final int originalImageX;
         final int zoomedInImageX;
         final int originalImageY;
         final int zoomedInImageY;
      
         CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_POSITION:
         {
         
            final int quantizedX = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.x);
            final int quantizedY = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.y);
         
            zoomedInImageX = Math.max(quantizedX, 0);
            originalImageX = zoomedInImageX / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
         
            zoomedInImageY = Math.max(quantizedY, 0);
            originalImageY = zoomedInImageY / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
         
         }
      
         final int zoomedInImageWidth;
         final int originalImageWidth;
         final int zoomedInImageHeight;
         final int originalImageHeight;
      
         CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_DIMENSION:
         {
         
            final int minWidth = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
            final int quantizedMinWidth = quantize.applyAsInt(minWidth);
            final int potentialWidth = quantizedMinWidth + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
            zoomedInImageWidth = Math.min(drawingArea.width, potentialWidth);
            originalImageWidth = zoomedInImageWidth / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
         
            final int minHeight = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);
            final int quantizedMinHeight = quantize.applyAsInt(minHeight);
            final int potentialHeight = quantizedMinHeight + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
            zoomedInImageHeight = Math.min(drawingArea.height, potentialHeight);
            originalImageHeight = zoomedInImageHeight / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
         
         }
      
         g.setPaint(gui.cursorColor);
      
         System.out.println(zoomedInImageX + " -- " + zoomedInImageY + " -- " + zoomedInImageWidth + " -- " + zoomedInImageHeight + " ---- " + originalImageX + " -- " + originalImageY + " -- " + originalImageWidth + " -- " + originalImageHeight + " ----- " + rectangle + " - " + drawingArea);
      
         g
            .drawImage
            (
               gui.image,
               zoomedInImageX,
               zoomedInImageY,
               zoomedInImageX + zoomedInImageWidth,
               zoomedInImageY + zoomedInImageHeight,
               originalImageX,
               originalImageY,
               originalImageX + originalImageWidth,
               originalImageY + originalImageHeight,
               //gui.transparencyColor,
               null
            )
            ;
      
      }
   
      DRAW_GRID_LINES:
      {
      
         if (gui.hasGridLines && gui.screenToImagePixelRatio > 1)
         {
         
            g.setPaint(gui.gridLinesColor);
            g.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(1));
         
            IntStream
               .range(rectangle.y, rectangle.y + rectangle.height)
               .forEach
               (
                  eachIndex ->
                  {
                  
                     if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                     {
                     
                        g
                           .drawLine
                           (
                              rectangle.x,
                              eachIndex,
                              rectangle.x + rectangle.width,
                              eachIndex
                           )
                           ;
                     
                     }
                  
                  }
               )
               ;
         
            IntStream
               .rangeClosed(rectangle.x, rectangle.x + rectangle.width)
               .forEach
               (
                  eachIndex ->
                  {
                  
                     if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                     {
                     
                        g
                           .drawLine
                           (
                              eachIndex,
                              rectangle.y,
                              eachIndex,
                              rectangle.y + rectangle.height
                           )
                           ;
                     
                     }
                  
                  }
               )
               ;
         
         }
      
      }
   
   }

   // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.repaint();
   // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.revalidate();

}
```

And here is a complete runnable example.

```java
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class GUI
{

   private static final Function<String, Border> TITLED_BORDER =
      title ->
         BorderFactory
            .createTitledBorder
            (
               null,
               title,
               TitledBorder.CENTER,
               TitledBorder.TOP
            )
            ;

   private static final Color CLEAR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
   private static final Point OFF_SCREEN = new Point(-1, -1);

   public static final int ARBITRARY_VIEW_BUFFER = 200;
   private static final int MIN_PEN_SIZE = 1;
   private static final int MAX_PEN_SIZE = 10;
   private static final int MIN_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO = 1;
   private static final int MAX_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO = 30;
   private static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_ROWS = 26;
   private static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_COLUMNS = 24;

   private final JFrame frame;
   private final JScrollPane drawingAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane();

   private BufferedImage image;
   private Color transparencyColor = Color.WHITE;
   private Color cursorColor = Color.BLACK;
   private Color gridLinesColor = Color.GRAY;
   private boolean hasGridLines = true;
   private int penSize = 1;
   private int screenToImagePixelRatio = 10;

   public static void main(final String[] args)
   {
   
      final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   
      IntStream
         .range(0, 20)
         .forEach(i -> image.setRGB(i, i, Color.RED.getRGB()))
         ;
   
      new GUI(image);
   
   }

   public GUI()
   {
   
      this(DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_ROWS, DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_COLUMNS);
   
   }

   public GUI(final int numImagePixelRows, final int numImagePixelColumns)
   {
   
      this(new BufferedImage(numImagePixelColumns, numImagePixelRows, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
   
   }

   public GUI(final BufferedImage image)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(image);
   
      try
      {
      
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
      
      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      
      }
   
      INITALIZING_METADATA_INSTANCE_FIELDS:
      {
      
         this.image = image;
      
      }
   
      this.frame = new JFrame();
   
      this.frame.setTitle("Paint");
      this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   
      this.frame.add(this.createMainPanel());
   
      this.frame.pack();
      this.frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      this.frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }

   private JPanel createMainPanel()
   {
   
      final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   
      mainPanel.add(this.createCenterPanel(),   BorderLayout.CENTER);
   
      return mainPanel;
   
   }

   private JPanel createCenterPanel()
   {
   
      final GUI gui = this; //useful when trying to differentiate between different this'.
   
      final JPanel mainPanel;
   
      CREATE_MAIN_PANEL:
      {
      
         mainPanel = new JPanel();
         mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      
      }
   
      final JPanel drawingPanel;
   
      final Runnable UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT;
      final Runnable RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH;
      final Runnable REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL;
   
      final BiFunction<Point, Integer, Point> originalToZoomed =
         (original, ratio) ->
            new Point(original.x * ratio, original.y * ratio)
            ;
   
      final BiFunction<Point, Integer, Point> zoomedToOriginal =
         (zoomed, ratio) ->
            new Point
            (
               (zoomed.x - (zoomed.x % ratio)) / ratio,
               (zoomed.y - (zoomed.y % ratio)) / ratio
            )
            ;
   
      CREATE_DRAWING_PANEL:
      {
      
         SET_UP_DRAWING_PANEL:
         {
         
            drawingPanel = new JPanel();
         
            drawingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(drawingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
         
            drawingPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(123, 456)));
         
         }
      
         REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL =
            () ->
            {
            
               drawingPanel.repaint();
               drawingPanel.revalidate();
            
            }
            ;
      
         RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH =
            () ->
            {
            
               final var thingToFocus = drawingPanel;
            
               drawingPanel.removeAll();
            
               final Dimension drawingArea = gui.deriveDrawingAreaDimensions();
            
               final IntUnaryOperator quantize =
                  num ->
                     num - (num % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio)
                     ;
            
               final Box.Filler box =
                  new Box.Filler(drawingArea, drawingArea, drawingArea)
                  {
                  
                     @Override
                     protected void paintComponent(final Graphics dontUse)
                     {
                     
                        super.paintComponent(dontUse);
                     
                        if (!(dontUse instanceof Graphics2D g))
                        {
                        
                           throw new RuntimeException("Unknown graphics type = " + dontUse);
                        
                        }
                     
                        DRAW_DRAWN_PIXELS:
                        {
                        
                           final Rectangle rectangle  = gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();
                        
                           //We are only drawing a subsection because we may be working with GIGANTIC images.
                           //If we attempt to draw the whole image, performance will drop like a rock.
                           CALCULATE_SUBSECTION_TO_DRAW:
                           {
                           
                              final int x = rectangle.x;
                              final int y = rectangle.y;
                              final int width = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
                              final int height = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);
                           
                              g.setBackground(gui.transparencyColor);
                              g.clearRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, width, height);
                           
                           }
                        
                           DRAW_SUBSECTION_OF_IMAGE:
                           {
                           
                              final int originalImageX;
                              final int zoomedInImageX;
                              final int originalImageY;
                              final int zoomedInImageY;
                           
                              CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_POSITION:
                              {
                              
                                 final int quantizedX = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.x);
                                 final int quantizedY = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.y);
                              
                                 zoomedInImageX = Math.max(quantizedX, 0);
                                 originalImageX = zoomedInImageX / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                              
                                 zoomedInImageY = Math.max(quantizedY, 0);
                                 originalImageY = zoomedInImageY / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                              
                              }
                           
                              final int zoomedInImageWidth;
                              final int originalImageWidth;
                              final int zoomedInImageHeight;
                              final int originalImageHeight;
                           
                              CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_DIMENSION:
                              {
                              
                                 final int minWidth = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
                                 final int quantizedMinWidth = quantize.applyAsInt(minWidth);
                                 final int potentialWidth = quantizedMinWidth + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                                 zoomedInImageWidth = Math.min(drawingArea.width, potentialWidth);
                                 originalImageWidth = zoomedInImageWidth / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                              
                                 final int minHeight = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);
                                 final int quantizedMinHeight = quantize.applyAsInt(minHeight);
                                 final int potentialHeight = quantizedMinHeight + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                                 zoomedInImageHeight = Math.min(drawingArea.height, potentialHeight);
                                 originalImageHeight = zoomedInImageHeight / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                              
                              }
                           
                              g.setPaint(gui.cursorColor);
                           
                              System.out.println(zoomedInImageX + " -- " + zoomedInImageY + " -- " + zoomedInImageWidth + " -- " + zoomedInImageHeight + " ---- " + originalImageX + " -- " + originalImageY + " -- " + originalImageWidth + " -- " + originalImageHeight + " ----- " + rectangle + " - " + drawingArea);
                           
                              g
                                 .drawImage
                                 (
                                    gui.image,
                                    zoomedInImageX,
                                    zoomedInImageY,
                                    zoomedInImageX + zoomedInImageWidth,
                                    zoomedInImageY + zoomedInImageHeight,
                                    originalImageX,
                                    originalImageY,
                                    originalImageX + originalImageWidth,
                                    originalImageY + originalImageHeight,
                                    //gui.transparencyColor,
                                    null
                                 )
                                 ;
                           
                           }
                        
                           DRAW_GRID_LINES:
                           {
                           
                              if (gui.hasGridLines && gui.screenToImagePixelRatio > 1)
                              {
                              
                                 g.setPaint(gui.gridLinesColor);
                                 g.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(1));
                              
                                 IntStream
                                    .range(rectangle.y, rectangle.y + rectangle.height)
                                    .forEach
                                    (
                                       eachIndex ->
                                       {
                                       
                                          if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                                          {
                                          
                                             g
                                                .drawLine
                                                (
                                                   rectangle.x,
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.x + rectangle.width,
                                                   eachIndex
                                                )
                                                ;
                                          
                                          }
                                       
                                       }
                                    )
                                    ;
                              
                                 IntStream
                                    .rangeClosed(rectangle.x, rectangle.x + rectangle.width)
                                    .forEach
                                    (
                                       eachIndex ->
                                       {
                                       
                                          if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                                          {
                                          
                                             g
                                                .drawLine
                                                (
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.y,
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.y + rectangle.height
                                                )
                                                ;
                                          
                                          }
                                       
                                       }
                                    )
                                    ;
                              
                              }
                           
                           }
                        
                        }
                     
                        // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.repaint();
                        // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.revalidate();
                     
                     }
                  
                  }
                  ;
            
               box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            
               drawingPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
               drawingPanel.add(box);
               drawingPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            
               REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run();
            
            }
            ;
      
         RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH.run();
      
      }
   
      final JPanel drawingSettingsPanel;
   
      CREATE_DRAWING_SETTINGS_PANEL:
      {
      
         drawingSettingsPanel = new JPanel();
         drawingSettingsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(drawingSettingsPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      
         final JSpinner screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu;
      
         SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO_DROP_DOWN_MENU:
         {
         
            screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu =
               new JSpinner
               (
                  new SpinnerNumberModel
                  (
                     this.screenToImagePixelRatio,
                     MIN_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO,
                     MAX_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO,
                     1
                  )
               )
               ;
         
            screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu
               .addChangeListener
               (
                  event ->
                  {
                  
                     if (!(screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu.getValue() instanceof Integer iii))
                     {
                     
                        throw new IllegalStateException();
                     
                     }
                  
                     this.screenToImagePixelRatio = iii;
                  
                     RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH.run();
                  
                  }
               );
         
         }
      
         final JCheckBox hasGridLinesCheckBox;
      
         HAS_GRID_LINES_CHECK_BOX:
         {
         
            hasGridLinesCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            hasGridLinesCheckBox.setText("Activate Grid Lines");
            hasGridLinesCheckBox.setSelected(true);
            hasGridLinesCheckBox
               .addActionListener
               (
                  event ->
                  {
                  
                     this.hasGridLines = hasGridLinesCheckBox.isSelected();
                  
                     REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run();
                  
                  }
               )
               ;
         
         }
         
         final JButton repaint = new JButton("REPAINT");
         repaint.addActionListener(event -> REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run());
      
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(new JLabel("SCREEN pixels = 1 IMAGE pixel"));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(hasGridLinesCheckBox);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(repaint);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      
      }
   
      CREATE_CENTERED_DRAWING_PANEL:
      {
      
         final JPanel centeredDrawingPanel = new JPanel();
         centeredDrawingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centeredDrawingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(drawingPanel);
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      
         UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT =
            () ->
               this.drawingAreaScrollPane
                  .setBorder
                  (
                     BorderFactory
                        .createCompoundBorder
                        (
                           TITLED_BORDER
                              .apply
                              (
                                 "Drawing Area -- "
                                 + gui.image.getHeight()
                                 + " rows and "
                                 + gui.image.getWidth()
                                 + " columns"
                              ),
                           BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        )
                  )
                  ;
      
         UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT.run();
      
         this.drawingAreaScrollPane.setViewportView(centeredDrawingPanel);
      
      }
   
      mainPanel.add(drawingSettingsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      mainPanel.add(this.drawingAreaScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   
      return mainPanel;
   
   }

   private static void print(final String text)
   {
   
      System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " -- " + text);
   
   }

   private Dimension deriveDrawingAreaDimensions()
   {
   
      return
         new Dimension
         (
            this.image.getWidth() * this.screenToImagePixelRatio,
            this.image.getHeight() * this.screenToImagePixelRatio
         )
         ;
   
   }

}
```

Comment: _"... I added a button that just triggers a `repaint()` ..."_, have it repaint whenever the _JScrollPane_ view port is adjusted, or zoomed.

Comment: @Reilas That definitely answers half of my question. Ty vm! If you are able to answer the other half, I would encourage you to post your full response as an answer, and I would accept it if it meets my needs.

Comment: What is the other half of your question?

Comment: @Reilas The why of how this occurs. I don't want to just slap on quick fixes without understanding why I am doing it and why they are necessary. If I was ok with that, I would be coding in JavaScript :P

Comment: `gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();` might be your first mistake, maybe, instead, look at the clipping rectangle of the `Graphics` context. `if (!(dontUse instanceof Graphics2D g))` is also pointless, I think since 1.3 or 4 your guaranteed to get a `Graphics2D` instance

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't fully understand - I see a method called `getClipBounds`, which appears to be what you are talking about. What does that give me over my original way?

Comment: @MadProgrammer WOW, so that fixed it. Why on earth? Do you have any insight why?

Comment: The clip rectangle is how Swing paints only a part of the component for efficiency. For example if you use repaint(?, ?, ?, ?) you can create your own clipping area. Compare the Rectangle you calculate with your original method with the clipping area used by Swing to see what the difference is. Note, when I tried the suggestion it still didn't work for me, but maybe I didn't change it correctly.

Comment: @camickr I switched `final Rectangle rectangle  = gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();` to be `final Rectangle rectangle  = g.getClipBounds();`, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @camickr And based on what you are saying, I actually have written a lot redundant code. Am I understanding you correctly here? Or is the way I did it (`g.drawImage...`) still the correct way? Or am I misinterpreting you entirely?

Comment: 1) Yes, that is how I changed my code. 2) When I drag the vertical scrollbar down it seems to paint correctly. However when I drag it up I sometimes see a square where the top part of the square is not painted. Sometimes it self corrects when I do down/up again. Not sure what is happening. 3) I never really understand how zooming works so I have no suggestions. 4) I was just trying to state that even though you were calculating a rectangle the size of the viewport the clip rectangle is only a few pixels high so only a small area of the viewport is repainted. You still need to scale the image.

Comment: Maybe you can use the scale() and translate() methods of the Graphics2D class to simplify the code. Or maybe use an AffineTransform. I think that is what I see in other postings.

Comment: First, `JScrollPane` is very optimised, you really don't want to mess with it.  Second, as has been stated, the coordinates between the view rect and the component may be different, since they are different component contexts - you're basically reaching out side of the component's own context and trying to use to use a different components context - not a good idea

Comment: @camickr Oh, sometimes, the visual defect only shows up if you scroll right or left. In the example I posted above, it actually only shows up for me if I do it right to left. So I scroll down, then right. As for zoom, really, I am just using `Graphics::drawImage` to do my zooming. I provide the scale at which I am doing this as method parameters. The scale is influenced by my JSpinner-set value.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, I understand how what I did was a bad practice. But I'm still lost on how your strategy ended up solving things. Ultimately, we both provide rectangles, and they both seem to be covering the same areas and with the same x/y coordinates. So what changed between them that caused different behaviour?

Comment: @davidalayachew The view rectangles are providing different offsets - the clip will be within the components coordinate context, the view rect from the `JScrollPane` will be within it's - different contexts

Comment: @MadProgrammer Maybe the word context means something that I am not understanding then. Yes, the offsets are different, and the rectangles have different contexts (which I am interpreting to mean that they have different backgrounds from which they came from). But ultimately, they both ended up creating the same image. The only difference is that one creates unpleasant visual artifacts until the `JComponent` has repainted and revalidated itself. So my question is, if the final image being created is the same upon repaint, what is the significance of context that it would influence this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm just not seeing the connection between what context would give me and what would cause this problem to be solved. But of course, I am starting to think that you are saying words that I don't understand the full meaning of either. You may need to ELI5 this to me.

Comment: @davidalayachew So, a component has two "contexts" in reference to it's location, the local "context" and it's external "context", so when painting, you use the "local" context, where the `0x0` is the top/left position of the component (as opposed to it's external context, which the parent uses to position the component - not try and mix the contexts, it messes things up :P

Comment: I should say “coordinate context”, so a “local” context will have the top/left corner at 0x0, where as the “container” or “external” context will have the top/left corner be the position within its parent container. Graphics/custom painting  are defined in the “local coordinate context”

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, so I now understand about contexts. But if you look at my code, I am essentially recreating a local context from an external context. I am offsetting and transforming my coordinates from the external rectangle to recreate the local. Obviously unideal, and I firmly agree that it is a bad practice that I intend to fix ASAP.

Comment: @MadProgrammer But that does not answer my question. Ultimately, I am seeing that I end up with the exact same rectangle -- either because it was created that way, or I manually massaged it into shape. My question remains -- if the resulting rectangle is the same, why is it working with one method when it wasn't with the other? Does Rectangle have some hidden properties that I do not know about?

Comment: @davidalayachew *"I am offsetting and transforming my coordinates from the external rectangle to recreate the local"* and that seems wrong to me, because the `Graphics` context is already translated to the represent the local context. You don't seem to be translating the external coordinate context to the local context (so that the `x/y` position is relative to the `0x0` position of the component itself)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, if that is the case, maybe that is where my problem is. I'll dig into that another time. Still, ty for the help.

Comment: @MadProgrammer in my shock and surprise, I overlooked something that camickr just pointed out -- while I managed to "translate" the x and y coordinates from the external context into the local one, I completely neglected to notice that the width and height are actually completely different between the old way that I started with and the clip bounds that you pointed out. I am pretty sure that that was what I was missing. But I will delve further into that another time to confirm.

Comment: One thing I am noticing though -- for me, I was struggling to understand the problem because I wanted to understand exactly how the break occurred. I'm slowly starting to realize that I don't need to delve into the realms of undefined behaviour and all the ways that my code could break. I should instead just stick to above mentioned best practices and not try to understand every single edge case of it until needed (as in, I need to use the edge case, and therefore, I need to understand it). Thank you to both you and @camickr for all of the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I look at your code the more confused I am. I must admit I don't recognize half of the coding constructs you are using.

However, from what I do understand, it appears to me you don't understand the basics of how custom painting works. You should read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a basic example.

Some tips:

1. the code for the painting should be self contained in a class.
2. you pass parameters to the class to control the painting. Parameters such as rows, columns, image, zoom factor.
3. the paintComponent method will directly reference the above parameters.
4. you override the `getPreferredSize()` method to control the size of your component. This method would likely reference your image and the zoom factor. The way you currenlty set the size buy creating a new Box.Filler is unique to say the least.
5. the code for your ActionListeners should not be recreating the drawing panel. Instead you just invoke a method on the panel to update a property and then invoke revalidate() and repaint().

Because you don't follow the standard coding conventions the code becomes overly complex (to me anyway). I can't think of any good reasons for the code to be structured this way.

I am still confused about your claim that using:

```
//final Rectangle rectangle  = gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();
final Rectangle rectangle  = g.getClipBounds();
```

fixes the problem. As I stated earlier it did not fix the problem for me.

Did you try displaying the Rectangle in both cases to compare the values? Do you understand what the differences mean? I'm not understanding your discussion with MadProgrammer about the "context". In both cases the Rectangle uses the proper x/y location relative to (0, 0) of the components. The difference is that your approach uses a larger area since the width/height values will be the size of the viewport, not the size of the scroll distance.

In any case I downloaded your code again and retested. The strangest thing is that your original code now works (after I made a couple of coding changes since your syntax doesn't work for me with JDK11).

I also simplified the drawImage statement to just use:

```
g.drawImage(gui.image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() * gui.screenToImagePixelRatio, image.getHeight() * gui.screenToImagePixelRatio, null);
```

and it still works for me.

So for what its worth here is the version of the code I'm testing on Windows 11, JDK11 that works:

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class GUI
{

   private static final Function<String, Border> TITLED_BORDER =
      title ->
         BorderFactory
            .createTitledBorder
            (
               null,
               title,
               TitledBorder.CENTER,
               TitledBorder.TOP
            )
            ;

   private static final Color CLEAR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
   private static final Point OFF_SCREEN = new Point(-1, -1);

   public static final int ARBITRARY_VIEW_BUFFER = 200;
   private static final int MIN_PEN_SIZE = 1;
   private static final int MAX_PEN_SIZE = 10;
   private static final int MIN_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO = 1;
   private static final int MAX_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO = 30;
   private static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_ROWS = 26;
   private static final int DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_COLUMNS = 24;

   private final JFrame frame;
   private final JScrollPane drawingAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane();

   private BufferedImage image;
   private Color transparencyColor = Color.WHITE;
   private Color cursorColor = Color.BLACK;
   private Color gridLinesColor = Color.GRAY;
   private boolean hasGridLines = true;
   private int penSize = 1;
   private int screenToImagePixelRatio = 10;

   public static void main(final String[] args)
   {
   
      final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   
      IntStream
         .range(0, 20)
         .forEach(i -> image.setRGB(i, i, Color.RED.getRGB()))
         ;

      new GUI(image);
   
   }

   public GUI()
   {
   
      this(DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_ROWS, DEFAULT_IMAGE_PIXEL_COLUMNS);
   
   }

   public GUI(final int numImagePixelRows, final int numImagePixelColumns)
   {
   
      this(new BufferedImage(numImagePixelColumns, numImagePixelRows, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
   
   }

   public GUI(final BufferedImage image)
   {
   
      Objects.requireNonNull(image);
   
      try
      {
      
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());

      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
      
      }
   
      INITALIZING_METADATA_INSTANCE_FIELDS:
      {
      
         this.image = image;
      
      }

      this.frame = new JFrame();
   
      this.frame.setTitle("Paint");
      this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   
      this.frame.add(this.createMainPanel());
   
      this.frame.pack();
      this.frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      this.frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }

   private JPanel createMainPanel()
   {
   
      final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   
      mainPanel.add(this.createCenterPanel(),   BorderLayout.CENTER);
   
      return mainPanel;
   
   }

   private JPanel createCenterPanel()
   {
   
      final GUI gui = this; //useful when trying to differentiate between different this'.
   
      final JPanel mainPanel;
   
      CREATE_MAIN_PANEL:
      {

         mainPanel = new JPanel();
         mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      
      }
   
      final JPanel drawingPanel;
   
      final Runnable UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT;
      final Runnable RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH;
      final Runnable REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL;
   
      final BiFunction<Point, Integer, Point> originalToZoomed =
         (original, ratio) ->
            new Point(original.x * ratio, original.y * ratio)
            ;
   
      final BiFunction<Point, Integer, Point> zoomedToOriginal =
         (zoomed, ratio) ->
            new Point
            (
               (zoomed.x - (zoomed.x % ratio)) / ratio,
               (zoomed.y - (zoomed.y % ratio)) / ratio
            )
            ;

      CREATE_DRAWING_PANEL:
      {

         SET_UP_DRAWING_PANEL:
         {

            drawingPanel = new JPanel();

            drawingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(drawingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            drawingPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(123, 456)));

         }

         REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL =
            () ->
            {

               drawingPanel.repaint();
               drawingPanel.revalidate();

            }
            ;

         RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH =
            () ->
            {

               final var thingToFocus = drawingPanel;

               drawingPanel.removeAll();

               final Dimension drawingArea = gui.deriveDrawingAreaDimensions();

               final IntUnaryOperator quantize =
                  num ->
                     num - (num % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio)
                     ;

               final Box.Filler box =
                  new Box.Filler(drawingArea, drawingArea, drawingArea)
                  {

                     @Override
                     protected void paintComponent(final Graphics dontUse)
                     {

                        super.paintComponent(dontUse);

/*
                        if (!(dontUse instanceof Graphics2D g))
                        {

                           throw new RuntimeException("Unknown graphics type = " + dontUse);

                        }
*/
                        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)dontUse;

                        DRAW_DRAWN_PIXELS:
                        {

                           final Rectangle rectangle  = gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();
//                           final Rectangle rectangle  = g.getClipBounds();

                           //We are only drawing a subsection because we may be working with GIGANTIC images.
                           //If we attempt to draw the whole image, performance will drop like a rock.
                           CALCULATE_SUBSECTION_TO_DRAW:
                           {

                              final int x = rectangle.x;
                              final int y = rectangle.y;
                              final int width = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
                              final int height = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);

                              g.setBackground(gui.transparencyColor);
                              g.clearRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, width, height);

                           }

                           DRAW_SUBSECTION_OF_IMAGE:
                           {

                              final int originalImageX;
                              final int zoomedInImageX;
                              final int originalImageY;
                              final int zoomedInImageY;

                              CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_POSITION:
                              {

                                 final int quantizedX = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.x);
                                 final int quantizedY = quantize.applyAsInt(rectangle.y);

                                 zoomedInImageX = Math.max(quantizedX, 0);
                                 originalImageX = zoomedInImageX / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;

                                 zoomedInImageY = Math.max(quantizedY, 0);
                                 originalImageY = zoomedInImageY / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;

                              }

                              final int zoomedInImageWidth;
                              final int originalImageWidth;
                              final int zoomedInImageHeight;
                              final int originalImageHeight;

                              CALCULATE_ORIGINAL_DIMENSION:
                              {

                                 final int minWidth = Math.min(rectangle.width, drawingArea.width);
                                 final int quantizedMinWidth = quantize.applyAsInt(minWidth);
                                 final int potentialWidth = quantizedMinWidth + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                                 zoomedInImageWidth = Math.min(drawingArea.width, potentialWidth);
                                 originalImageWidth = zoomedInImageWidth / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;

                                 final int minHeight = Math.min(rectangle.height, drawingArea.height);
                                 final int quantizedMinHeight = quantize.applyAsInt(minHeight);
                                 final int potentialHeight = quantizedMinHeight + gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;
                                 zoomedInImageHeight = Math.min(drawingArea.height, potentialHeight);
                                 originalImageHeight = zoomedInImageHeight / gui.screenToImagePixelRatio;

                              }

                              g.setPaint(gui.cursorColor);

//                              System.out.println(zoomedInImageX + " -- " + zoomedInImageY + " -- " + zoomedInImageWidth + " -- " + zoomedInImageHeight + " ---- " + originalImageX + " -- " + originalImageY + " -- " + originalImageWidth + " -- " + originalImageHeight + " ----- " + rectangle + " - " + drawingArea);

                                g.drawImage(gui.image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() * gui.screenToImagePixelRatio, image.getHeight() * gui.screenToImagePixelRatio, null);
/*
                              g
                                 .drawImage
                                 (
                                    gui.image,
                                    zoomedInImageX,
                                    zoomedInImageY,
                                    zoomedInImageX + zoomedInImageWidth,
                                    zoomedInImageY + zoomedInImageHeight,
                                    originalImageX,
                                    originalImageY,
                                    originalImageX + originalImageWidth,
                                    originalImageY + originalImageHeight,
                                    //gui.transparencyColor,
                                    null
                                 )
                                 ;
*/
                           }

                           DRAW_GRID_LINES:
                           {

                              if (gui.hasGridLines && gui.screenToImagePixelRatio > 1)
                              {

                                 g.setPaint(gui.gridLinesColor);
                                 g.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(1));

                                 IntStream
                                    .range(rectangle.y, rectangle.y + rectangle.height)
                                    .forEach
                                    (
                                       eachIndex ->
                                       {

                                          if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                                          {

                                             g
                                                .drawLine
                                                (
                                                   rectangle.x,
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.x + rectangle.width,
                                                   eachIndex
                                                )
                                                ;

                                          }

                                       }
                                    )
                                    ;

                                 IntStream
                                    .rangeClosed(rectangle.x, rectangle.x + rectangle.width)
                                    .forEach
                                    (
                                       eachIndex ->
                                       {

                                          if (eachIndex % gui.screenToImagePixelRatio == 0)
                                          {

                                             g
                                                .drawLine
                                                (
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.y,
                                                   eachIndex,
                                                   rectangle.y + rectangle.height
                                                )
                                                ;

                                          }

                                       }
                                    )
                                    ;

                              }

                           }

                        }

                        // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.repaint();
                        // gui.drawingAreaScrollPane.revalidate();
                     
                     }
                  
                  }
                  ;
            
               box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            
               drawingPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
               drawingPanel.add(box);
               drawingPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            
               REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run();
            
            }
            ;
      
         RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH.run();
      
      }
   
      final JPanel drawingSettingsPanel;
   
      CREATE_DRAWING_SETTINGS_PANEL:
      {
      
         drawingSettingsPanel = new JPanel();
         drawingSettingsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(drawingSettingsPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      
         final JSpinner screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu;
      
         SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO_DROP_DOWN_MENU:
         {
         
            screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu =
               new JSpinner
               (
                  new SpinnerNumberModel
                  (
                     this.screenToImagePixelRatio,
                     MIN_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO,
                     MAX_SCREEN_TO_IMAGE_PIXEL_RATIO,
                     1
                  )
               )
               ;
         
            screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu
               .addChangeListener
               (
                  event ->
                  {
                  
/*
                     if (!(screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu.getValue() instanceof Integer iii))
                     {

                        throw new IllegalStateException();

                     }
*/
                     int iii = ((Integer)screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu.getValue()).intValue();
                     this.screenToImagePixelRatio = iii;

                     RECREATE_DRAWING_AREA_FRESH.run();

                  }
               );

         }

         final JCheckBox hasGridLinesCheckBox;
      
         HAS_GRID_LINES_CHECK_BOX:
         {
         
            hasGridLinesCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            hasGridLinesCheckBox.setText("Activate Grid Lines");
            hasGridLinesCheckBox.setSelected(true);
            hasGridLinesCheckBox
               .addActionListener
               (
                  event ->
                  {
                  
                     this.hasGridLines = hasGridLinesCheckBox.isSelected();
                  
                     REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run();
                  
                  }
               )
               ;
         
         }
         
         final JButton repaint = new JButton("REPAINT");
         repaint.addActionListener(event -> REPAINT_DRAWING_PANEL.run());
      
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(screenToImagePixelRatioDropDownMenu);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(new JLabel("SCREEN pixels = 1 IMAGE pixel"));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(hasGridLinesCheckBox);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(repaint);
         drawingSettingsPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      
      }
   
      CREATE_CENTERED_DRAWING_PANEL:
      {
      
         final JPanel centeredDrawingPanel = new JPanel();
         centeredDrawingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centeredDrawingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(drawingPanel);
         centeredDrawingPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      
         UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT =
            () ->
               this.drawingAreaScrollPane
                  .setBorder
                  (
                     BorderFactory
                        .createCompoundBorder
                        (
                           TITLED_BORDER
                              .apply
                              (
                                 "Drawing Area -- "
                                 + gui.image.getHeight()
                                 + " rows and "
                                 + gui.image.getWidth()
                                 + " columns"
                              ),
                           BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)
                        )
                  )
                  ;
      
         UPDATE_DRAWING_PANEL_BORDER_TEXT.run();
      
         this.drawingAreaScrollPane.setViewportView(centeredDrawingPanel);
      
      }
   
      mainPanel.add(drawingSettingsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      mainPanel.add(this.drawingAreaScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   
      return mainPanel;
   
   }

   private static void print(final String text)
   {
   
      System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " -- " + text);
   
   }

   private Dimension deriveDrawingAreaDimensions()
   {
   
      return
         new Dimension
         (
            this.image.getWidth() * this.screenToImagePixelRatio,
            this.image.getHeight() * this.screenToImagePixelRatio
         )
         ;
   
   }

}
```

Note: just because it works doesn't mean I think you should use it. I believe the code should be restructured to better follow Swing custom painting conventions.

Comment: Hey, thank you for posting this. First off, I actually made a couple of mistakes. As you pointed out, while I "converted" the x and y coordinates to be equivalent across contexts, the height and width are different. In my surprise to see that the suggested solution worked, I forgot to check height and width.

Comment: As for the poor organization, you are right on the money. I am still not great at that, as you have seen from several of my other questions that you have answered. This is my first time delving into custom painting, so I will refactor my solution to follow the protocols for custom painting that you pointed out.

Comment: As for your simplification, I feel like I originally started out with that, but then switched away from it because of performance problems. I may have made a premature decision however. I will experiment with this and give it a shot.

Comment: Also LOL on the `getPreferredSize`. I actually spent a very long time trying to figure out how on earth I could accomplish doing a zoom. The best that I could think of was to recreate whatever component, but bigger. I then tried to find the simplest `JComponent` I could find, and ended up landing on `Box.Filler`. In retrospect, setting the size of `setPreferredSize` is mind-numbingly obvious that my lack of creativity here amazes me LOL.

Comment: Though, in my defense, I recall seeing somewhere that someone said resizing `Box.Filler` in particular was discouraged. Doesn't change the fact that I should have tried it before trying whatever I was doing LOL

Comment: I do not understand point 5 however. Can you go into more detail?

Comment: Otherwise though, thanks for the insight! You, @MadProgrammer, and a couple others consistently do a lot for us junior devs learning Swing. The time and effort you all put into this is appreciated.

Comment: *I do not understand point 5* - how do you change the text/icon in a JLabel? Do you create a new JLabel? No, you invoke the setText(...) or setIcon(...) method. So when youi want to change the zoom factor do you create a new drawing panel? No, you invoke a method on the drawing panel to set the zoom parameter. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571767/131872 as a simple example. It does a rotation, not a zoom, buy you should get the idea.

Comment: Note it is NOT a complete example because it does not implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to consider how the size of the image changes as the angle of rotation changes. It does demonstes the concept of responding to an event to change a property of the class.

Comment: Perfect, ty vm. In that case, this answer meets my needs, and I now understand what to do. Ty again!

Comment: Oh, and about the code not working -- I am developing using JDK 21. Really, I am using the beta version of JDK 22, but everything I am doing should work just fine with JDK 21. My compile command is `javac --enable-preview --source 21 GUI.java`. My run command is `java --enable-preview GUI`.